# Symfony2 - How to access the service in a custom console command?

Tags: php, symfony, console, command

I am new to Symfony. I have created a custom command which sole purpose is to wipe demo data from the system, but I do not know how to do this.

In the controller I would do:

```
$nodes = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MyFreelancerPortfolioBundle:TreeNode')
    ->findAll();

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
foreach($nodes as $node)
{
    $em->remove($node);
}
$em->flush();
```

Doing this from the execute() function in the command I get:

```
Call to undefined method ..... ::getDoctrine();
```

How would I do this from the execute() function? Also, if there is an easier way to wipe the data other than to loop through them and remove them, feel free to mention it.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to be able to access the service container your command needs to extend [Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ContainerAwareCommand.php).

See the Command documentation chapter - [Getting Services from the Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container).

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
// ... other use statements

class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        // ...
```

Answer (score 15):

Since **Symfony 3.3** (May 2017) you can use Dependency Injection in commands with ease.

Just use [PSR-4 services autodiscovery](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/#4-use-psr-4-based-service-autodiscovery-and-registration) in your `services.yml`:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    App\Command\:
        resource: ../Command
```

Then use common **Constructor Injection** and finally even `Commands` will have clean architecture:

```
final class MyCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var SomeDependency
     */
    private $someDependency;

    public function __construct(SomeDependency $someDependency)
    {
        $this->someDependency = $someDependency;

        // this is required due to parent constructor, which sets up name 
        parent::__construct(); 
    }
}
```

This will (or already did, depends of time reading) become standards since **Symfony 3.4** (November 2017), when [commands will be lazy loaded](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-lazy-commands).

Comment: How, do I register these Commands in the Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application()?